# Understanding the big O notation

Tags: algorithm, big-o

Some standard books on Algorithms produce this:

> 0 ≤ f(*n*) ≤ c⋅g(*n*) for all *n* > *n*<sub>0</sub>

While defining big-O, can anyone explain to me what this means, using a strong example which can help me to visualize and understand big-O more precisely?

Comment: Did you try Googling? E.g. [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation).

Comment: For a record, you can consider including the complete definition of big Oh in your question "A function f(n) is of order at most g(n) - that is, f(n) = O(g(n)) - if a positive real number c and positive integer N exist such that f(n) <= c g(n) for all n >= N. That is, c g(n) is an upper bound on f(n) when n is sufficiently large."

Comment: This has a nice example in the question itself.
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754718/big-oh-notation-formal-definition

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assume you have a function `f(n)` and you are trying to classify it - is it a big O of some other function `g(n)`.

The definition basically says that `f(n)` is in `O(g(n))` if there exists two constants C,N such that

```
f(n) <= c * g(n) for each n > N
```

Now, let's understand what it means.

Start with the `n>N` part - it means, we do not "care" for low values of `n`, we only care for high values, and if some (final number of) low values do not follow the criteria - we can silently ignore them by choosing `N` bigger then them.

Have a look on the following example:

[image]

Though we can see that for low values of n: `n^2 < 10nlog(n)`, the second quickly catches up and after `N=10` we get that for all `n>10` the claim `10nlog(n) < n^2` is correct, and thus `10nlog(n)` is in `O(n^2)`.
The constant `c` means we can also tolerate some multiple by constant factor, and we can still accept it as desired behavior (useful for example to show that `5*n` is `O(n)`, because without it we could never find `N` such that for each `n > N`:  `5n < n`, but with the constant `c`, we can use c=6 and show `5n < 6n` and get that `5n` is in `O(n)`.

Answer (score 0):

This question is a math problem, not an algorithmic one.

You can find a definition and a good example here: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/259063/big-o-interpretation

As @Thomas pointed out, Wikipedia also has a good article on this: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Big_O_notation

If you need more details, try to ask a more specific question.

Comment: This is more of a comment then an answer.