# How do I prove that y = n^2 does not belong to O(1) using formal definition of Big-O?

Tags: big-o

I understand that classifying in Big-O is essentially having an "upper-bound" of sort so I understand it graphically, I don't understand is how to use the Big-O formal definition to solve this types of problems. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Maybe this is already answered in https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3255/big-o-how-do-you-calculate-approximate-it?rq=1, https://stackoverflow.com/questions/487258/what-is-a-plain-english-explanation-of-big-o-notation?rq=1, or https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2754718/big-oh-notation-formal-definition?rq=1?

Comment: for this specific problem, i dont think so

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Although there are platforms better suited for this question than SO, since this gets purely mathematical, understanding this is fundamental for using big-O also in a Computer Science context, so I like the question. And understanding your particular example will likely shed some light on what big-O is in general, as well as provide some practical intuition. So I will try to explain:

We have a function *f(n) = n<sup>2</sup>*. To show that it is not in *O(1)*, we have to show that it grows faster than a function *g(n) = c* where *c* is some constant. In other words, that *f(n) > g(n)* **for sufficiently large *n***.

What does sufficiently large mean? It means that for any constant *c*, we can find an *N* so that *f(n) > g(n)* **for all** *n > N*.

This is how we define asymptotic behaviour. Your constant function may be larger than *f(n)*, but as *n* grows enough, you will eventually reach a point where *f(n)* remains larger forever. How to prove it?

Whatever constant *c* you choose - however large - we can construct our *N*. Let us say *N = √c*. Since *c* is a constant, so is *√c*.

Now, we have *f(n) = n<sup>2</sup> > c = g(n)* whenever *n > √c*.

Therefore, *f(n)* is not in *O(1)*. □

The key here is that we found an **constant** *N* (that is, which depends on our constant *c* but not on our variable *n*) such that this inequivalence holds. It can take some wrapping one's head around it, but doing a few other simple examples can help get the intuition.

Comment: may i ask why is g(n) is equal to c, where c is some constant? im a little confused as the formal definition states that "f(n) is always greater than or equal to zero and is always less than or equal to cg(n)."

Comment: You are comparing with the class of constant functions *O(1)*. The class of constant functions can be defined as any function *g(n) = c*, where *c* is a constant. The confusion here is that you can choose *c* as large as you want, but the point is that it doesn't depend on *n*. This means that however large *c* is, an *O(n)* function will always reach larger values eventually, as *n* grows.